# JUnit 4: how to get test name inside a Rule?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit-rule

JUnit 4: how to get test name inside a `Rule`? e.g.,

```
public class MyRule extends ExternalResource {

    @Before
    public void before() {
        // how to get the test method name to be run?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a `@Rule` with the test name, don't reinvet the wheel, just use the built-in [`TestName`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestName.html) `@Rule`.

If you're trying to build your own rule that adds some logic to it, consider extending it. If that isn't an option either, you could just copy it's [implementation](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/TestName.java).

To answer the question in the comment, like any other `TestRule`, `ExternalResouce` also has an `apply(Statement, Description)` method. You can add functionality to it by overriding it, just make sure you call the super method so you don't break the `ExternalResource` functionality:

```java
public class MyRule extends ExternalResource {
    private String testName;

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        // Store the test name
        testName = description.getMethodName();
        return super.apply(base, description);
    }

    public void before() {
        // Use it in the before method
        System.out.println("Test name is " + testName);
    }
}
```

Comment: MyRule needs to extends ExternalResource because its contains Before() and After(). But it does not have starting(Description d) method. How to get method name inside MyRule? thanks.